# Variable names with spaces in equations

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I want to write a fomula

```
\begin{equation}
    fractional bandwidth = \frac{f_U-f_L}{f_C} \geq 0.25
\end{equation}
```

but it can't have any space between "fractional" and "bandwidth"
How can I do that? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\text` of package amsmath to format text in math equations.

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
...

\begin{equation}
    \text{fractional bandwidth} = \frac{f_U-f_L}{f_C} \geq 0.25
\end{equation}
```

[image]

However, if these words were intended to be formatted like they are but with a space in between, you can insert spaces in math mode like this (a full list of spacing commands can be found [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Spacing_in_math_mode)).

```
\begin{equation}
    fractional \: bandwidth  = \frac{f_U-f_L}{f_C} \geq 0.25
\end{equation}
```

[image]